# tipos de datos python

Tags: python

A partir de la tupla mostrada de distintos tipos de datos (str, int y float), elaborar un programa para recorrerla y crear tres listas en las que se guarden esos tipos de datos, es decir una lista para los datos de tipo int, una lista para los datos de tipo float y una lista para los datos de tipo str, e imprimir cada una una de las listas con sus respectivos tipos de datos por separado, así:

Tupla = (1, 2, "Hola", 3.3, "hello", 5, 4.3)

Output

Datos de tipo int: [1, 2, 5]

Datos de tipo float: [3.3, 4.3]

Datos de tipo str: [Hola, hello]

me podrian ayudar con este ejercicio de python por favor :D

Comment: Buen día, este no es un sitio para que alguien haga tu tarea/trabajo, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy buenas estimado, la solución que te brindo te funcionará con cualquier tipo de dato, es decir, si posees una colección que tiene dentro integers, floats, objetos, strings, etc. No importa porque el algoritmo los clasifica sin problema.

**Solución:**

```
def deconstruct_by_type(collection: list) -> list: 
    types: dict[type, list[object]] = {}
    for item in collection:
        if not item.__class__ in types: 
            types[item.__class__] = [] 
        types[item.__class__].append(item)
    return types 

target: tuple = (1, 23, 4.45, "Helo") 
result = deconstruct_by_type(target)
print(result)
```

Lo que hacemos es utilizar una estructura de datos bastante útil llamada diccionario, también la encontrarás con las denominaciones de maps, hash_maps, hash_sets, tablas de hash, etc, donde por cada elemento de mi colección a filtrar extraemos su tipo y validamos si ya se encuentra almacenada en nuestro diccionario; de ser el caso, empezamos a agregar a todos los elementos que vuelvan a coincidir con el tipo ya ingresado y, si no, almacenamos el tipo de dato como indicador para nuestro proceso de filtración y proseguimos con el llenado respectivo.

Te recomiendo leer sobre tablas de hash para que entiendas mejor este algoritmo.

Comment: muchas gracias colega, es lo que necesitaba

Comment: @andres889 A la orden estimado, cualquier cosa no dude en preguntar

Answer (score 1):

Luego de estas explicaciones  lee el mensaje en la última parte.

### Primero que tenemos

1. Una tupla con distinto tipos de datos.
2. Me piden devolver los datos de la tupla divididos en listas que comparten el mismo tipo de datos.

> @Async0014.hpp te ha dado una muy buena respuesta, y es más cercana a
> la cual usarías en un ambiente profesional, por lo que mi respuesta
> será más orientada a lo que encontrarías en una entrevista de trabajo o
> una tarea donde te piden resolverlo sin el uso de librerías.

### Algoritmo:

1. Creamos una variable `result` esta variable es una diccionario, donde las llaves son el tipo de dato y los valores la lista de elementos de dicho tipo, ejemplo `result = {“<class ‘int’>” : [1,2,5], <class 'str'>: ['Hola', 'hello'], <class 'float'>: [3.3, 4.3]]` pero comenzamos con un diccionario vacío  `result = dict()`
2. Creamos un bucle que va a comenzar en 0 y termina en el último elemento de las tuple dada.  (el último elemento es `tamaño_de_la_lista_de_entrada – 1` recuerda las listas son índice 0 es decir el primer elemente comienza en 0 por lo que el ultimo elemente es el tamaño -1. tuples siguien la mismo (indice 0).
3. Tenemos un condicional, preguntamos si el tipo de dato NO es parte de las llaves del diccionario, si esto es verdad, creamos la llave y añadimos el primer elemento en forma de lista  `result[type(arr[i])] = [arr[i]]`. en este caso `arr` es tu tupla.
4. Si por el contrario la llave existe, sacamos la lista ya existente, añadimos el nuevo elemento y lo guardamos nuevamente en la llave. ( Esto puede ser mejorado y se puede escribir de una manera más corta pero si no tienes experiencia con python puede ser confuso, así que lo dividí en varios pasos )
5. Finalmente recorremos el diccionario imprimiendo las llaves y los datos

```
arr = (1, 2, "Hola", 3.3, "hello", 5, 4.3)

result = dict()

for i in range(len(arr)):

    if type(arr[i]) not in result:
        result[type(arr[i])] = [arr[i]]

    else:
        list_a = result[type(arr[i])]
        list_a.append(arr[i])
        result[type(arr[i])] = list_a

for k, v in result.items():
    print(f'Elementos tipo {k}: {v}')
```

### Resultado

```
Elementos tipo <class 'int'>: [1, 2, 5]
Elementos tipo <class 'str'>: ['Hola', 'hello']
Elementos tipo <class 'float'>: [3.3, 4.3]
```

### Análisis:

1. No estoy seguro si te piden resolver el caso en una complejidad o un Big O en específico (si no sabes que es complejidad o Big O no te preocupes puedes aprenderlo luego, pero básicamente es una forma de medir el uso del tiempo y el espacio de cada algoritmo. El mejor algoritmo es el constante O(1) o uno logarítmico O(logn))
2. Podemos utilizar un algoritmo de búsqueda, en este caso puede ser un algoritmo de fuerza bruta, es decir básico con una complejidad de tiempo O(1) ya que recorremos la tupla una sola vez, pero con una complejidad de espacio de O(n) ya que en el peor de los casos el diccionario será del mismo tamaño que la tupla.

### Nota

Stackoverflow normalmente es para consultar con una comunidad sobre problemas que has encontrado, esto quiere decir, la comunidad espera ver que has intentado, o al menos que piensas hacer. Entiendo que comenzando es difícil saber por dónde comenzar,  pero si quieres ayuda, y no quieres que la pregunta sea cerrado por los moderadores, es bueno que intentes colocar que estás pensando, como crees que se podría solucionar, no necesariamente en código, simplemente dejale saber a la comunidad tu proceso y que tienes en mente (o cuanto conocimiento tienes).